# performance on encryption and decryption

Tags: asp.net, performance, encryption, dictionary

in my web application i m using AES to encrypt or decrypt the data. Acording to my search it is one of the fastest algorithm for encryption and actually it is very fast i think.

but sometimes i realy need to encrypt or decrypt many string and it causes performance problem.

for this manner i thought that i can use a dictionary to store the encrypted and plain versions of a string so that in second time i can get the encrypted string from dictionary instance. Below code is my dictionary implementation.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _veryFastDict;

    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetVeryFastDictInstance()
    {
        return _veryFastDict ?? (_veryFastDict = new Dictionary<string, string>());
    }
```

and in encryption code is below

```
    public static string VeryFastEncrypt(string text)
    { 
        if (GetVeryFastDictInstance().ContainsKey(text))
        {
            return GetVeryFastDictInstance()[text];
        }

        ///string encryptedText 
        /// encryption code

        GetVeryFastDictInstance().Add(text,encryptedKey);

        return encryptedKey;
     }
```

is it a good approach and is there any possible problem for this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Instead of redoing the same work its good to store the encrypted results in some data structure. This saves the time of recalculating the same encrypted message.

This strategy is useful when you have less encryption strings but lot of occurrences of those strings.

But this can also have the problem of **size**, If you have lot of strings which needs to be encrypted but they have less occurrences. This can degrade the performance as it will grow the size of Data structure (probably a hash map,hash table though it has O(1) search capability). Memory demand will increase.

In such situations, encrypting large block of data is a workaround. Because AES is a block cipher. It works on chunks of data and it is really fast for large no. of blocks. But it is less preferred for small data as encryption overhead is more than advantage.

Conclusion :

1. Use data structure dictionary,hash map etc. for storing PT-CT pairs if less strings and more occurrences are present. Keep size of Data structure in mind.
2. Use encrypt once and replace all occurrences approach (You don't need additional data structure in this approach)
3. For more strings and less occurrences, check for option 2 or block encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Its an acceptable one, but I see here the following issues.

1. You do not lock the `.add()` call, so you may lead to corrupted data because the Dictionary is static.
2. You do not take care the case of get too many data on your Dictionary. You must take care to delete some of your data time to time, or else you may end up with eating all your memory, if your data grows up too much. The dictionary is good one to find a string, because make inside indexing, but if your data will be come too much, then you may lose in performance because each time you insert a new string its take longer... so you may think to add an extra counter with each string and count how many times is used, so you keep only the minimum of string... and delete the rest time to time.